# PHP Short tag error on codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, xampp, mamp

Codeigniter version 2.1.4 application running on MAMP on my localhost has no errors,It was working fine with xampp on windows 7 too.
I copied the entire files to another system and tried running on xampp with windows 10,it results with many errors,the home page loads fine,but once i login it results with many type of error's.

**Error 1**- Session problems

```
undefined-if($this->session->userdata('usertype')!="user"){
```

**Error 2**- Undefined Variable

**Error 3**- Values retrieved from database show's as below

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property:
stdClass::$package_price
```

Is it because of windows 10 or any xampp issues?Any other files to be changed on xampp or in my codeigniter application?My wordpress sites are running fine without any changes to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve the issue by enabling short tag option on both php.ini and .htaccess.Added the below line on .htaccess

```
php_flag short_open_tag on
```

The below link helped me.

[Enable PHP short tags using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116823/enable-php-short-tags-using-htaccess)